# How to select :host with a class in css for web components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

In the new v1 web components specs, you can use `:host` to target the custom element. But then I attached a class `A` to the custom element, and had a css selector `:host.A`, but its styles are not being applied. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `.a:host` and `:host('.a')`?  Can you give the exact css and an example of what the element looks like?  From my reading it seems like it is a [pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector) and pseudo-classes can appear [anywhere](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) in a sequence of simple selectors.  Also what browser are you using, and does it specify it supports it?

Comment: I tried doing `.a:host` and `:host('.a')` but neither worked.

Comment: Are you using chrome? If not this question will explain why its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468701/why-does-the-host-selector-only-work-in-chrome-with-platform-js

Comment: I am using latest version of chrome actually.

Comment: this worked :host(.a)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#selectordef-host-function):

> For example, say you had a component with a [shadow tree](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-shadow-tree) like the following:
>
> ```
> <x-foo class="foo">
>     <"shadow tree">
>         <div class="foo">...</div>
>     </>
> </x-foo>
> ```
>
> For a stylesheet within the shadow tree:
>
> - ...
> - '`:host(.foo)`' matches the `<x-foo>` element.

As OP has commented, that would, in this case, translate to:

```css
:host(.a) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this shouldn't work, but for me it does:

```
:host-context(.dialog) .overlay { background: green; }
```

for a class, directly attached to the template (not something higher up)

```
<my-component class='dialog><div class='overlay'></div></my-component>
```